# How to trigger the hover event for a div element along with all its children using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to trigger hover event for a div element along with all its children 
using jquery.

Currently I am writing the hover event as below:

```
$("#divID").hover(function() 
  { 
   //code on hovering in 
  }, 
  function() 
  { // code on hovering out 

  });
```

When I move cursor to any child element, the "code on hovering out" is getting executed, where as I want the 'code on hoverig in' to be executed becuase as I am still hovering over the chidren of #divID.

Please suggest the suitable method to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The way

```
$("#divID").hover(function() { 

 });
```

Should work. You shouldn't worry about children as they are part of your Parent div. The even works on your children too.

The way `$("#divID").children()` is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, the code is working, but if I directly jump to the chidren of the div the event is not triggering.

Comment: $("#divID").hover(function() 
      { 
       //code on hovering in 
      }, 
      function() 
      { // code on hovering out 
      
      }); 

When I move cursor to any child element, the "code on hovering out" is getting executed, where as I want the 'code on hoverig in' to be executed becuase as I am still hovering over the chidren of #divID.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the trigger function:
I think something like that will do.

```
$(someElement).trigger('mouseenter');
```

Answer (score 0):

## 1 - Running function when entering `#parent` and its children

[`.hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) only runs once when hovering, if you want to run the function when you hover the div itself but also when you hover child div here's how you do it:

Instead of selecting only the parent div I also select all his child divs using the `,` separator. This allows me to select multiple queries. Code below:

```js
$("#parent, #parent > div").hover(function() {

  console.log('hovering in');

}, function() {

  console.log('hovering out');

});
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  top: 40px;
  left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">

  <div id="child"></div>

</div>
```

---

## 2 - Running function multiple time while hovering `#parent`

Or maybe you're just looking to run the function multiple time when hovering. In this case, use the [`.mousemove`](https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) event and then use [`.mouseleave`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) to run the function when the mouse leaves `#parent`.

```js
$("#parent").mousemove(function() {

  console.log('hovering in');

});


$("#parent").mouseleave(function() {

  console.log('hovering out');

});
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  top: 40px;
  left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">

  <div id="child"></div>

</div>
```